# Swift button resizing animation

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimation

I'm trying to animate button resizing, but all I get is instant already resized view. What am i doing wrong?

p.s. sorry for my bad english

swift 5

```
 UIView.animate(withDuration: 10) {
            self.button.frame.size = CGSize(width: 195, height: 195)
            self.button.frame.size.width += 100
            self.button.frame.size.height -= 100
            self.button.center.y += 200
        }
```

first three lines inside curly brackets don't work as i expect, but the last one change the position of button as it has to

Comment: Do not change the frame. Change the bounds.

Comment: Also it is meaningless to set the size and the width in the same animation.

Comment: @matt i changed frame to bounds, and now button resizes to needed  size, spawns  at top-left corner and animates its moving to the center position. What's wrong with my code? |
 
self.button.bounds.size.width -= 100
self.button.bounds.size.height -= 100

Comment: Spawns? Where’s that in your code?

Comment: Nowhere. that's all the code inside the animation brackets. I think it just resizes to the top-left corner immediately

Comment: Well, I can't see your new code, but I can assure you that changing the bounds size, of itself, will not cause the button to move. You still really don't want to show some context? You want help but you want me to operate in the dark?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who tried to  help me, after some researches I decided to use

```
self.button.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.5, y: 0.5)
```

CGAffineTransform, instead of changing bounds or frames.
Now everything works fine

Answer (score 1):

You don't perform any arithmetics inside `UIView.animate`, you just set the final values of the constants that you want animated:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 10) {
    self.button.frame.size.width = 10 // The new width of self.button
}
```

Same concept applies for any frame/width/height constants or even completely new frames.